# How to twinkle shadow using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, for-loop, toggle, setinterval

I am a newbie and I was trying to figure out on how to twinkle box-shadow on an element but I couldn't.

So far I got [this](http://jsbin.com/eceziw/2).

Theoretically, it's supposed to work. I used `setInterval` inside for loop but it didn't work. Also, I think I got some issues with toggle function.

The main point is that when page starts loading I want that element's box-shadow to start twinkling from very fast to very slow and eventually it would stop.

Do you have any suggestions?!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I agree with Praveen Vijayan. Here is a showcase with css3 key-frames: http://jsfiddle.net/ufP7h/

```
@-webkit-keyframes twinkly {
    0%   { box-shadow: 0 0 10px #6c9; }
    100% { box-shadow: 0 0 10px red; }
}
@-moz-keyframes twinkly  {
     0%   { box-shadow: 0 0 10px #6c9; }
    100% { box-shadow: 0 0 10px red; }
}
@-ms-keyframes twinkly  {
     0%   { box-shadow: 0 0 10px #6c9; }
    100% { box-shadow: 0 0 10px red; }
}

#twinkle {
    -webkit-animation: twinkly 1s alternate infinite;
    -moz-animation: twinkly 1s alternate infinite;
    -ms-animation: twinkly 1s alternate infinite;
}
```

​

Comment: Not the answer to the question, but at least a nice demo how kenyframes work.

Comment: This is close to what I wanted, but could you tell why for loop isn't working? What I wanted to do is that when page loads an element starts twinkling very fast and then goes slowly.                                                                                                  for ( i=0; i<1000; i+=100) {
    setInterval(twinkle, i);
  }

Comment: I am afraid I cannot help you with that.

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to do some thing like this - http://jsbin.com/eceziw/4

```
$(function() {
   var x = 0;  
   function twinkle() {   
   if(x){
      $('#twinkle').addClass('shadowAnim');
      x =0;
   }else{
      $('#twinkle').removeClass('shadowAnim');
      x=1;
   }                         
 }
  setInterval(twinkle, 1000);  
 });
```

But, its better to use CSS3 key-frame animation.

Comment: Can I also use setInterval inside for loop?

Comment: Thats a bad idea. whats the purpose?

Comment: I wanted so that it would start twinkling slow and then twinkle very fast! Is it possible? Thnx in advance